# Как задать возвращение имени с токеном для Django API

Tags: django, api, framework

Есть simpleJWT и Django RESTFRAMEWORK. Мне нужно вместе с токеном вернуть name или email, но что-то не пойму как это сделать.

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

User = get_user_model()


class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, style={
                                     "input_type":   "password"})
    password2 = serializers.CharField(
        style={"input_type": "password"}, write_only=True, label="Confirm password")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "password",
            "password2",
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data["username"]
        email = validated_data["email"]
        password = validated_data["password"]
        password2 = validated_data["password2"]
        if (email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).exists()):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"email": " Email should be unquil."})
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"password": "The two passwords differ."})
        user = User(username=username, email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework import response, decorators, permissions, status
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from .serializers import UserCreateSerializer

User = get_user_model()

@decorators.api_view(["POST"])
@decorators.permission_classes([permissions.AllowAny])
def registration(request):
    user_data = request.user
    serializer = UserCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return response.Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)        
    user = serializer.save()
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    
    res = {
        "refresh": str(refresh),
        "access": str(refresh.access_token),
        "user": str(user),
    }
    
    return response.Response(res, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: а в чём сложность добавить это в ваш `res`? или я не правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: JWT токен только для регестрации прописан, а мне нужно вернуть как-то это дело для авторизации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благо есть [документация](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). Но тем не менее повторюсь:

1. Нужно добавить `rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication` в настройки `REST_FRAMEWORK`, а именно в `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`.
2. Для аутентификации достаточно указать в `urlpatterns` следующий путь - `path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair')` (путь может быть и `api/login`, тут как вам удобно).

Если же вам нужно как то дополнить данные отдаваемые в `TokenObtainPairView` вы можете написать свою `view` унаследованную от `TokenObtainPairView`.

Как пример:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        data['email'] = self.user.email

        return data

class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair')
]
```

Comment: Разобрался слегка другим путём, но всё же логика понятна, и суть такая же. Благодарю.